# Can 2 MongoDB instances running on the same server point to the same data folder ?

Tags: linux, mongodb, replication, upgrade

I am in the process of upgrading my MongoDB replica set from 2.6 to 3.2. We are planning to create another replica set on the same set of machines as an option to fallback in case something goes wrong. 
In this context, I am trying to find out if the new mongod instance that i would install (on each of these servers to form a replica set) can point to the already existing data files folder being used by the live mongod instance ? Or do i have to take a dump and restore via mongodump/mongorestore ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that if you are planning to upgrade your instance to 3.2 without upgrading to WiredTiger engine.
If upgrading to WiredTiger enine, than you need to reindex your data as MMAP and Wiredtiger engines are not compatible.

To run two instances of mongoDB using same data:

1. create a directory for your second instance.
2. soft link all data from first instance directory except lock files.
3. run your second instance with --dbpath argument pointing to second instance directory.